# SOSL on Lookup Fields not working.

Tags: sosl

How do we write SOSL that searches lookup fields. Example My query looks this.

"FIND \'*Mark*\' in all fields returning Account(Id, Name, User.Name)"

Here it doesn't search User with keyword Mark.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SOSL doesn't search "lookup" fields. For example:

```
FIND {Acme} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, FirstName, LastName, Account.Name)
```

Won't return contacts with the account called Acme; it will return any contacts that have any reference to Acme in the description field, name fields, etc.

Use a regular SOQL if you want to find accounts owned by a user:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Owner.Name LIKE 'Mark%'
```

Or, use SOSL with another term, and use an additional WHERE clause:

```
FIND {term} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Id, Name, Owner.Name WHERE Owner.Name LIKE 'Mark%')
```

Comment: I guess, SOSL for standard object relationship is working(however, on custom object it doesn't work despite of Lookup or MD relationship). Please confirm.
Have tested standard object with following query(Burlington is account name): 
**FIND {Burlington} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact**

Comment: sfdxfox, the problem is that it will only support an AND operation between the FIND and WHERE clauses, which is annoying.  The best solution I have found is to do a SOQL query and just combine the lists.  It avoids creating triggers to copy data around as SOSL cannot search formula fields.

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with the OWD on the User Object and your sharing settings on User in your Org (esp if it's set to private). As of SU15, sharing is respected in all classes for the User Object.