# SOSL on lookup fields

Tags: apex, lookup, sosl

```
  String query = 'FIND \'*' + searchString + '*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Ticket__C (Region__r.name, Manager__c, Manager__r.name, Name, Notes__c), user(id,Name)';
```

I am searching with user name and results are zero.

Aim: when a string is entered, it should match with any of the fields and display the results. with the above query, it will match only with Ticket.name and shows zero results when i am searching for the user.name.

- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BO5mIAG#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_SEARCH_RESULT&id=9060G0000005qQHQAY

Says IT CAN NOT BE DONE.
So how to achieve If input is a user name, they should be able to see ticket records related to the user, which I am displaying on visualforce page.

any inputs please

Comment: What were you expecting to find?

Comment: @sfdcfox I have edited the question to add aim. I saw you replied to a post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92435/sosl-on-lookup-fields-not-working. I couldn't apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did. 
String query = 'FIND \'*' + searchString + '*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Ticket__C (Region__r.name, Manager__r, Manager__r.name, Name, Notes__c), user(id,Name)';

Manager__c  is a Lookup(User).

Ticket__c[] searchTickets= (Tickets__c[])searchList[0];

User[] searchUser = (User[])searchList[1];

in for looping user(){

if(user.id == manager id in ticket){

addTolistToDisplay.add(ticket__c object);

}